# How to distinguish radio and checkbox type in drupal

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I have a content type which consists four types of fields. checkbox, radio, select, select multiple

I'm using `field_info_instances('node','bundle_name')` in my custom module to get filed info for my content type. I need this info to use somewhere.

My question is, how can I distinguish the checkbox type and radio type.same problem for select and multi select also.

Here is the output
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, I've used **field_info_field** function, In the return array  I found the difference in cardinality.

The cardinality for checkbox is **-1** and for radio button is **1**. Similarly for select is 1 and multi select is -1

I found it myself, is there any better solution than this?

Answer (score 0):

A field has a cardinality property (meaning how many values it can have) and a type property (meaning what *general* sort of form element to use).

I say *general* because the field object itself does not dictate the exact widget. That is controlled by `options_field_widget_form()` [(docs here)](http://api.drupalecommerce.org/api/drupal/drupal!modules!field!modules!options!options.module/function/options_field_widget_form/7.x) which takes the field object and works out whether to use checkboxes or radio buttons based on the cardinality.

So yes you are right - examining the field object won't tell you which type of form element will be used, but you can assume it from the cardinality (so long as no-one has overridden `options_field_widget_form()`).

Multiple cardinality gets checkboxes; single cardinality means you are only allowed one choice, hence a set of radio buttons. By the way 1 and -1 are not the only possible cardinalities. -1 means unlimited. A cardinality of, say, 3 will also get a set of checkboxes.